# Powershell Cygwin copy data with Rsync remote as variable

Tags: linux, powershell, rsync, file-server

I have a problem with Cygwine's rsync. With a Powershell script I am trying to transfer directories from a Novell server to a Windows server

The path for the source is a variable that comes from a CSV file

```
Function CopyRsync ([string]$source,[string]$dest){   
        $sourceRoot = "root@"+$source +"/"        
        $dest = "/cygdrive/g/Shares/" +$dest

cmd.exe /C "e:\cwRsync\bin\rsync.exe" -vrts --progress --whole-file --no-compress --no-checksum  -e "/cygdrive/e/CWrsync/bin/ssh" $sourceRoot $dest --delete-before         
    }

$novel = 'server.domaine.local:/media/nss/rep01/Com/Com dir Soins info'
$dfs = "C:\temp\Rsync"
CopyRsync -source $novel -dest $dfs
```

If the source path in the variable does not contain a white space the script runs correctly, but if the path contains a  white space the content of the variable will be parsed with quotes and the script stop running because the SSH session recieve "root@... as user with quotes in the begining of user root like this

```
"E:\cwRsync\bin\rsync.exe" -vrts --progress --whole-file --no-compress --no-checksum -e /cygdrive/e/CWrsync/bin/ssh "root@server.domaine.local:/media/nss/rep01/Com/Com dir Soins info/" /cygdrive/g/Shares/C:\temp\Rsync --delete-before
```

How can I parse a variable to ignore the quote from script variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use Visual Studio Code and the code work well. I think the ISE IDE of Powershell not interpreting quotes correctly